# JWT refreshing with refresh token

Tags: node.js, jwt

I am building SPA app with its rest API and I cannot find information when I should refresh JWT using refresh token. Should I do this when I will receive 401 HTTP status from server (JWT expired) or for example every 15 minutes if possible (before JWT will expire)?

Comment: It's better to refresh token before expire, If not, you should store requests after get `401 HTTP` on your client side until token refreshed and resend them again because of reliability. If your expiration time was enough check it after login.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a security expert, but as far we know, we

1- login and save the received token

2- we put one interceptor that check every response (in angular it's easy, in react we usually use `axios` ...etc)

3- we check every response in the interceptor, if the response was `401` *and* the `expiration date` from the token has passed, we send a `refresh token` request and save the new token

to check expiration date you can use a library that decode the token like: [jwt-decode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode) on npm, (don't forget to wrap the process in `try...catch` in case somebody screw with the token) and you even can paste the token in https://jwt.io/ and see for your self the decoded token and check the expiration date.

4- repeat the last request with the new token should succeed.

5- if for example even the refresh token request failed, simply redirect the user to the login page

Comment: So are you parsing JWT on frontend and check expiration date? Doesn't everything crash when date in users computer isn't real? (in this situation date on server could pass but not in browser)

Comment: I put a not on decoding the token in the answer, no why would it crash, the worst case the token is invalid and request fails

Comment: Good answer. The only thing I'd add to this is that you should be using rotating refresh tokens with SPAs and not non-rotating refresh tokens (which should only be used with native apps). See https://auth0.com/blog/securing-single-page-applications-with-refresh-token-rotation/

Answer (score 1):

If the server is sending a proper error code in case of `access_token` expired then you can intercept the error code on the client-side and use the `refresh_token` you got earlier during authentication to get a new access token. You can repeat this process again and again until your refresh token gets expired. On that occasion, you should redirect the user to perform the authentication to get both the tokens.